# ListView items are transparent

Tags: android, listview

I'm reading a table from a database, and presenting it in a `ListView`:

```
Cursor cities = db.getTableData(DBTable.CITY, columns);
cityListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
        cities, 
        columns, 
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1},0);
citiesListView.setAdapter(cityListAdapter);
```

This works fine.

But because I'm gonna use this code multiple times, I decided to make a function out of it:

```
Cursor cities = db.getTableData(DBTable.CITY, columns);
cityListAdapter = MyDatabase.fillAdapter(cities,columns);
public static ListAdapter fillAdapter(Cursor cursor,String[] columns)
{
    return (new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainApplication.getAppContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            cursor, 
            columns, 
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1},0));
}
```

It works, but the items in ListView look kinda transparent! (very light gray).

In the previous code they looked just black.

Why is this happening? It's the exact same code put in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because in your second approach with your static method you call `getAppContext()` to get your context, but styles are not working with the application context.

Try to get another context there or set your theme for the application context programmatically like that:

```
getApplicationContext().setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
```

Comment: Genius. [And here goes some text to reach the minimum characters]